# Windows Form Calculations C#

Tags: c#, windows, decimal

I am working on Windows Tax Application using C#. One of the forms I have contains multiple Text Boxes (Decimals and Int) and totals of those text box values.

Ex: I have Txt1, Txt 2 and Tx 3 and TxtTotal

I want to be able to do on spot calculations, like as soon as user modifies the value of Txt 1, the total should get updated amount displayed on Txttotal, without clicking on any button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use the TextChanged event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make every input textbox of your form use the same TextChanged event and set the ReadOnly property to True for the TxtTotal

```
 // Here just to clarify, you could use 
 // the Form designer to register this event handler
 Txt1.TextChanged += onChanged;
 Txt2.TextChanged += onChanged;
 Txt3.TextChanged += onChanged;
 TxtTotal.ReadOnly = true;
```

now write the TextChanged event handler to something like this

```
 private void onChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int t1;
     int t2;
     int t3;

     Int32.TryParse(Txt1.Text, out t1);
     Int32.TryParse(Txt2.Text, out t2);
     Int32.TryParse(Txt3.Text, out t3);

     txtTotal.Text = (t1+t2+t3).ToString();
 }
```

This code assumes that every textbox contains an integer and doesn't care if the textbox is empty or contains a text that cannot be converted to an integer. In this case the value of the converted variable will be zero and doesn't change the result.

More code will be needed if you want to emit error messages. And if you have decimals then use an appropriate decimal variable and `decimal.TryParse` instead of `Int32.TryParse`

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you very much for your reply!! The code you shared is working, but, the total is getting messed up. . Ex: Initially t1, t2 and t3 had 1,1,1 each and Ttotal was 3 and I changed T1 from 1 to 5 , total got updated to 7, which is correct. Then I changed t2 value from 1 to 5 and Ttotal got updated from 7 to 15, where in it should have been 11.

Comment: That's strange. Just tested and this should not happen. Are you sure to have typed the code correctly? (in particular look at the final addition or at the txt boxes used in the TryParse)

Comment: Yes, I did..Here is the code private void onChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            int t1;
            int t2;
            int t3;

            Int32.TryParse(txtUINumWorkers1.Text, out t1);
            Int32.TryParse(txtUINumWorkers2.Text, out t2);
            Int32.TryParse(txtUINumWorkers2.Text, out t3);

            txtUINumWorkersTotal.Text = (t1+t2+t3).ToString();
         }

Comment: The last conversion uses again **txtUINumWorkers2.Text** instead of **txtUINumWorkers3.Text**

Comment: Oh...it is my bad, So stupid I am. I am so sorry..You are correct. Sorry to bother you. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93113/discussion-between-reed-and-steve).